# XSL: Combining text with results of tag processing

Tags: xslt

I have a tag which can contain a mix of text and xml tags to be processed. Assuming that for the tags I have xsl:templates defined, how do I build xsl so that the result of the transformation would be the text fragments and the results of the tag substitution in the same order they were in the original document?

Here is the source xml:

```
<diagnosis>
    Line 1
    Line 2
    <terminology code="1234"/>
    Line 3
</diagnosis>
```

The output should be something like this:

```
Line 1 Line 2 Description1234 Line 3
```

Description1234 is the result of a lookup for the code 1234. For now I am not concerned about how it will be done just how to splice it all together.

Comment: You should post an example. Show sample XML input and the *exact* expected result for that input. If you do this, you'll get an answer immediately; otherwise, you're tempting people to read your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how `<terminology/>` maps to "Description", so I assumed the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <!-- Final newline -->
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="terminology">
    <!-- Spaces are added at the front and... -->
    <xsl:text> Description</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@code"/>
    <!-- at the end of attribute -->
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <!-- Strip all white space, specifically the newlines -->
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's what I get when I run your example XML ('so.xml') through xsltproc:

```
~ zacharyyoung$ xsltproc so.xsl so.xml
Line 1 Line 2 Description1234 Line 3
```